# Problem with executing artisan commands while installing OctoberCMS

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, octobercms

I'm installing OctoberCMS on my server and while trying `php artisan october:install` or any artisan command, I'm encountering this error:

```
In Container.php line 891:

  Target class [cache] does not exist.


In Container.php line 889:

  Class "cache" does not exist
```

I was following this tutorial: https://octobercms.com/support/article/rn-13.

I tried to install it again.

I tried using `composer install`, `composer update` and `composer dump-autoload` but nothing changes.

My PHP version is 8.2.4

This is from my composer.json:

```
"name": "october/october",
    "description": "Built using October CMS: The Laravel-Based CMS Engineered For Simplicity",
    "type": "project",
    "homepage": "https://octobercms.com",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0.2",
        "october/rain": "^3.5",
        "laravel/framework": "^9.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.7"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5|^9.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.13"
```

I`m quite new in Laravel and OctroberCMS and I don't know what to do to remove these problems.

Do you have any tips?